# Responsive center navbar

Tags: javascript, html, css

My goal is to make a navbar which is centered in the web page and responsive like here on stack.

So far I managed with some research and tutorials make a navbar which is responsive but it spreads to the end of corners.

I tried to wrap it in a container like I do with content but it limited whole navbar to middle.

Then tried to add margin to left and right but when I got on smaller screens it became ugly.

So I want your opinions how to fix it or if there is some other preferred way to do navbars.

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="brand-title">Fruit Basket</div>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Are you saying you want the links to shift further inwards as the browser size increases?

Comment: I want what I have now, but with a change that when its on big screen that "logo" and links are on center like for example here on stackoverflow. When I did that with padding or container it messed with smaller screens view.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap the entire thing in a `header`, set `max-width: 800px; margin: 0 auto;` on the `nav` and move the `background-color` to `header`:

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

header {
  background-color: #333;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: space-between;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  max-width: 800px;
  color: white;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }

  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }

  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }

  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }

  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<header>
  <nav class="navbar">
    <div class="brand-title">Fruit Basket</div>
    <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
      <span class="bar"></span>
    </a>
    <div class="navbar-links">
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</header>
```

`margin: 0 auto` centers the `nav` and `max-width` caps how wide it can be. If you want it to be wider just change this property.

Comment: Thank you very much. Clean and understandble solve.

Comment: No problem @Angelll

Comment: One more thing. When I found my ways around this on my own. It could be solved with float. But I saw that we should avoid using float and focus more on flex and grid. So is that true to avoid using float in the fututre? @daniel_knights

Comment: I wouldn't say you *can't* use `float` (it's still good for positioning text around an element) but flex and grid give you much more to work with so it is a good idea to get as familiar as you can with them

Answer (score 0):

As per your comment:
"I want what I have now, but with a change that when its on big screen that "logo" and links are on center like for example here on stackoverflow. When I did that with padding or container it messed with smaller screens view. – Angelll"

What I understood is you need everything center in bigger screen.
Correct me If I am wrong.

As per my understanding I have found the solution and added in the below code snippet.
I have replaced the .navbar class justify-content property to center.

```js
const toggleButton = document.getElementsByClassName('toggle-button')[0]
const navbarLinks = document.getElementsByClassName('navbar-links')[0]

toggleButton.addEventListener('click', () => {
  navbarLinks.classList.toggle('active')
})
```

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
  position: relative;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #333;
  color: white;
}

.brand-title {
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  margin: .5rem;
}

.navbar-links {
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-links ul {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.navbar-links li {
  list-style: none;
}

.navbar-links li a {
  display: block;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 1rem;
}

.navbar-links li:hover {
  background-color: #555;
}

.toggle-button {
  position: absolute;
  top: .75rem;
  right: 1rem;
  display: none;
  flex-direction: column;
  justify-content: space-between;
  width: 30px;
  height: 21px;
}

.toggle-button .bar {
  height: 3px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  border-radius: 10px;
}

@media (max-width: 800px) {
  .navbar {
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: flex-start;
  }
  .toggle-button {
    display: flex;
  }
  .navbar-links {
    display: none;
    width: 100%;
  }
  .navbar-links ul {
    width: 100%;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li {
    text-align: center;
  }
  .navbar-links ul li a {
    padding: .5rem 1rem;
  }
  .navbar-links.active {
    display: flex;
  }
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
  <div class="brand-title">Fruit Basket</div>
  <a href="#" class="toggle-button">
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
  </a>
  <div class="navbar-links">
    <ul>
      <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">About</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

Comment: Must have explain it badly sorry. Already result I wanted was given by Daniel Knight perfectly. But still thank you for effort.